# Using ReportLab with Google App Engine (Python) - works locally but fails when deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, reportlab

I have a Google App Engine (Python) application successfully deployed and I've deployed several versions without problems. My most recent version that I've been developing locally now uses ReportLab to generate PDF downloads. This works fine locally, however now that I have tried to deploy the latest version, I'm getting a 500 error with the following in the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tools/2-0.376834985709780158/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pdftools
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tools/2-0.376834985709780158/pdftools.py", line 1, in <module>
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tools/2-0.376834985709780158/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py", line 19, in <module>
from reportlab import rl_config
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tools/2-0.376834985709780158/reportlab/rl_config.py", line 122, in <module>
_startUp()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tools/2-0.376834985709780158/reportlab/rl_config.py", line 92, in _startUp
if '~' in d: d = os.path.expanduser(d)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 268, in expanduser
    import pwd
ImportError: No module named pwd
```

I just wondered if anyone could shed any light on why this isn't working now deployed?

Comment: For some reason reportlab is trying to import ` pwd — The password database` which is not supported/meaningless on appengine.  You should look at how you are configuring reportlab for use on appengine.  Fro some reason '~' is being used in a path.  You need to work out why

Comment: This was fixed this week in reportlab, try checking out from their repo: https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/commits/f1913fcae595aae40ef7b0be5ba54238b7aab7ce

Answer (score 0):

Your log shows "ImportError: No module named pwd"

Do you have the pwd module?

You could check by trying to import it in an interactive python shell

Comment: that won't work, there is no interactive shell in the appengine runtime.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your help - the fix Greg linked to sorted out the issue, but appreciate the time you took to comment/explain.